# URL Variable of Native Magento customization tool uploader to preview the image?

Tags: php, ajax, image, magento, upload

In magento customization tool, you can put file upload option

but I would like that When you upload an image preview in the screen at least when you click on edit the product

which is the variable of the loaded image?
With The URL of the cart image link:

htt....MY-WEB.com/sales/download/downloadCustomOption/id/107/key/a5cae363d3d6cde2e9c6/

I test with:
img src=..
this URL and display ok, but which is the variable that takes this to interfere with an echo

Here they do with flash but if you do not have flash detected with ajax
http://demo.micosolutions.com/afup/ajax-flash-upload-pro-demo/ajax-flash-uploader-demo.html

I think these are the files that can talk about this:

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Options/Type/file.php

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** Deleted old answer because I misunderstood the question.

Ok this time I hope I understood correctly what you want. To get the URL of an custom option image from a product that was added to the cart you can get it from quote item:

```
    $item = $this->getItem();
    $optionIds = $item->getOptionByCode('option_ids');

    if( $optionIds ) {
      $options = array();
      foreach( explode( ',', $optionIds->getValue() ) as $optionId ) {
        $option = $this->getProduct()->getOptionById( $optionId );

        if( $option->getData( 'type' ) == 'file' ) {
          $option = $item->getOptionByCode( 'option_' . $optionId );

          $value = unserialize( $option->getData( 'value' ) );

          var_dump( $value );
          var_dump( Mage::getUrl( 'sales/download/downloadCustomOption', array( 'id' => $option->getId(), 'key' => $value[ 'secret_key' ] ) ) );

          echo '<img src="' . Mage::getUrl( 'sales/download/downloadCustomOption', array( 'id' => $option->getId(), 'key' => $value[ 'secret_key' ] ) ) . '"/>';
        }
      }
    }
```

Output: It var dumps download url and $value content ($value[ 'fullpath' ] is the location of the image file but it is forbiddon to access it from a browser - you will have to move the file to a different location in media folder where it will be accessable from the web).
echo will show the image.

$item is of type Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item (this code was tested in checkout/cart/index controller - your_page_url/index.php/checkout/cart -> code can be added at the top of template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml file to see how it works).

Comment: Thanks Domen, but really what I want is simpler just want to know the variable I need to do an "echo"
on page file.phtml that when I add to cart the product can give to edit and then I preview the image

I just need the variable that creates the image:

htt....MY-WEB.com/sales/download/downloadCustomOption/id/107/key/a5cae363d3d6cde2e9c6 /

for then the file.phtml

<img src="ht....6/" />

and so the image

** IN SUMMARY "only need this variable":
ht....MY-WEB.com/sales/download/downloadCustomOption/id/107/key/a5cae363d3d6cde2e9c6 /

Comment: ok, actually, if you click on edit, ie better come file.phtml is where in the product itself, but there does not work, in the cart ... default.phtml if it works but not how to remove the code that print is not necessary:

array(9) { ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["title"]=> string(34) "500.....Log.png" ["quote_path"]=> string(68) "/media/custom_options/quote/5/0/e46....

Comment: otherwise it would be wrong would be in the Product table, with the corresponding

I think it should be this line:
<dd><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?></dd>

it brings the url to access the image but with additional information:
<a href="http://www.leroybejarano.es/sales/download/downloadCustomOption/id/133/key/e4626....b62ef3/" target="_blank">Logo.png</a> 500 x 555 px.
but in any case the code does not print the echo
I try put a <img....>
to preview the image but not print the echo
thanks in advance

Comment: Regarding the $_formatedOptionValue - that variable is initialized with a call to $this->getFormatedOptionValue and that function was the base for the code in my answer so since you require the url without the formatting the code above is more suitable. Regarding $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] this value was never set in my tests so echoing it would cause a php error at best - the url with additional information that you are refering to is stored in $_formatedOptionValue['value'] (as can be seen if you <?php var_dump( $_formatedOptionValue ); ?>).

Comment: I can't find the edit button so I think that it would be better if you create a screen shot and draw on it where you would like to add what, wirte the exact url path to that page and how to get there. Then add that to your question.